# Need to restart server for the sake of mailing

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I developed an application having mailing operation in it, I am using tomcat 6 for deploying the application, I have ant script for building the war.

Now my problem is whenever I build the project, mailing stops working until I restart the server, and I came to know from one of professional saying that mailing context needs to be reloaded hence when you restart server the mailing works again.

But I don't want to restart the server every time I deploy new build, at the same time mailing should work. Is there any way to reload the mailing context when ever I build the project and deploy?

Comment: Please leave noise like sigs. & 'Thanks' out of questions.  Interesting question, BTW.  +1

Comment: I also wonder *why* it needs to be restarted

Answer (score 0):

To make context reload on application file modification change the context.xml configuration file

from

```
<Context>
```

to

```
<Context reloadable="true">
```